# System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in AutoMapper.dll. Additional information: Mapper not initialized

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, automapper

I use to find AutoMapper very simple to use.  I am struggling with the new version.  I have two types:

```
namespace VehicleMVC.Models
{
    public class CarModel
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string make { get; set; }
        public string model { get; set; }

    }
}
```

and:

```
namespace Business
{
    public class Car
    {

        private int _id;
        private string _make;
        private string _model;

        public int id
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value; }
        }

        public string make
        {
            get { return _make; }
            set { _make = value; }
        }

        public string model
        {
            get { return _model; }
            set { _model = value; }
        }

    }  
}
```

I have tried this in CarController:

```
public CarController()
        {
            service = new Service.Service();
            //Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Business.Car,CarModel>());
            //Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<List<CarModel>, List<Business.Car>>());
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.CreateMap<Business.Car, CarModel>();
            }       );
            config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

        }

private CarModel getCarModel(Business.Car BusinessCar)
        {
            CarModel CarModel = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<CarModel>(BusinessCar);
            return CarModel;
        }
```

The error I get is: An exception of type `'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in AutoMapper.dll.  Additional information: Mapper not initialized. Call Initialize with appropriate configuration.` but was not handled in user code.  What is wrong?

Comment: You've commented out the call to `Initialize`, which you need to call with the created config

Comment: Do you get the same error with the commented code? You need to call `Mapper.Initialize()` at some point

Comment: @stuartd, it says you should call Initialise or Mapper Configuration here: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started

Comment: The docs are misleading - you still have to call Mapper.Initialize with the configuration.

Comment: @stuartd, you are right.  It is working with both.  Post an answer and I will mark it for future visitors.

Comment: @w0051977 OK, done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you have created your configuration, you must initialize the mapper with it:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
     cfg.CreateMap<Business.Car, CarModel>();
};

config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
Mapper.Initialize(config);
```

Comment: Could you take a look at my other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38378459/map-configuration-or-unsupported-mapping    ?